# Spring boot mapstruct and modelMapper comparison confusing problem

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mapstruct, modelmapper

I have the following situation where i'm using spring data to fetch a list of entities,
and try to map those entities to a list of DTOs using mapstruct than i map those entities using modelMapper ( i do both mapping to analyse the slowness issue)

```
public  List<EntityADto> getListDto(String argument1, Integer argument2){
 //bloc 1 : mapstruct mapping
        List<EntityADto> result1=entityArepository.findAllByFilter( String argument1, Integer argument2).stream()
                .map(entityA -> mapstructMapper.toDto(entityA ))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
//end bloc 1

//bloc 2 : modelMapper mapping
          List<EntityADto> result2=entityArepository.findAllByFilter( String argument1, Integer argument2).stream()
                .map(entityA -> modelMapper.map(entityA , EntityADto.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
//end bloc 2
}
```

I found out that the slowness is may be coming from the FetchType, because the first bloc to execute is really slow but the next one will execute instantly. for example, if i place bloc 2 at the top of the getListDTO method  and bloc 1 bellow, bloc 2 will run super slow (around 1 minute) and bloc 1 will be super fast (around 0.1 second).

i tried to solve this using  FetchMode.JOIN and join fetch, but the result is the same:

```
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface EntityArepository extends JpaRepository< EntityA, Integer> {
   @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @Query(" SELECT o FROM EntityA o " +  
            " and (o.propertyOne = :argument1)"+
            " and (o.propertyTwo = :argument2 )"
    )
    List<EntityA> findAllByFilter(@Param("argument1") String argument1,
                                              @Param("argument2") Integer argument2 );
```

any suggestions please?

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if query you're using is correct, like it should have been something like "where (o.propertyOne is null or o.propertyOne = :argument1) and ...". Join fetch is used to fetch the other entities needed in one single operation rather than multiple operations.

Comment: thanks, what do you mean by operation here ? and do you have an idea why the bloc placed on top is always running faster then the bloc placed bellow (even if i interchange positions of blocs)

Comment: by multiple operations I mean hibernate will create and execute multiple queries. I'm not sure why the first execution is taking longer than the second.

Comment: ok i see what you mean, but note that "with FetchMode.JOIN set, FetchType is ignored and a query is always eager" from https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-fetchmode. And this eager type is what i'm trying to reach to see if it can help

Comment: okay, are you doing entity joins? if so, then only the join will help otherwise it won't have any effect. use the following configuration in application.properties; spring.jpa.show-sql=true, to see the queries generated at runtime, it will help you understand better what queries are executed.

Comment: thanks, i found an @transient function in EntityA that is issuing some requests to db and taking much time processing when called the first time, although the function is only using one collection in EntityA to get a total. i thought the function should be able to use them from the entity without querying db